# How to get a date in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH: mm: ss.SSSZ format

Tags: date, erlang

I want to get the current time, and format it in the following way:

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

(where SSS is the milliseconds and Z the time zone)

the code so far I have it as follows:

```
formatted_date() ->
  {{Y,M,D},{H,Min,S}} = erlang:localtime(),
  {Ms, _, _} = os:timestamp(),
  {Days, {Hours, _,_}} = calendar:time_difference(erlang:universaltime(), erlang:localtime()),
  Difference = 24*Days + Hours,
  Tz = [case Difference < 0 of
          true ->
            $-;
          false ->
            $+
        end | io_lib:format("~2..0B00",[Difference])],
  io_lib:format("[~4..0B-~2..0B-~2..0BT~2..0B:~2..0B:~2..0B.~3..0B ~5.s]",
                              [Y, M, D, H, Min, S, Ms, Tz]).
```

The fact is that it always returns the same Ms, therefore, I think that I am not doing it well, and in other questions I only see how to obtain the total time in milliseconds,  but not how to format it in this way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the library function [`calendar:system_time_to_rfc3339/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html#system_time_to_rfc3339-2) - it seems to fulfil all your requirements.

```
> calendar:system_time_to_rfc3339(os:system_time(millisecond), [{unit, millisecond}]).
"2021-03-03T18:42:08.497+05:30"
```

This function was added in Erlang/OTP 21.0, which was released in June 2018.

---

The reason your code always gets the same value for `Ms` is that the first value in the tuple returned by `os:timestamp/0` is *megaseconds*, not milliseconds; the three values are megaseconds, seconds and microseconds. This comes from a time when Erlang did not support large integers, so splitting up the timestamp was necessary. These days you can just call `os:system_time/1` or [a number of other functions, depending on what kind of time you need](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html), and get the result in a single integer.

Comment: An important aspect of this excellent answer is that it retrieves the time just once and converts it to the desired format. In the original code in the question, `localtime` is called twice and `universaltime` once, which means the calculations in the code are performed using multiple different time values, and it's possible that the timezone offset could change between the retrievals of these different times, yielding an incorrect result.

Comment: This is not working to me. Now I'm trying to get os:timestamp() {Mega, Seconds, Micro} and format it to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`, but I can't find any way to return the milli...

Comment: Okey, I think I know why it doesn't work for me, since I have a `io_lib:format/2` , to which I have to pass an `atom (), string () or binary ()`, and this function returns a `DateTimeString` and I need to convert it to `string ()`

Comment: The return value of `system_time_to_rfc3339` should count as a `string()`, so you could pass it to `io_lib:format` like this: `io_lib:format("Current timestamp: ~s~n", [calendar:system_time_to_rfc3339(os:system_time(millisecond), [{unit, millisecond}])])`

Comment: This doesn't work because the version of erlang that I'm working with is 17, and this function, is of a higher version. So... I'm looking for a function that allows me to do that and was in version 17

Comment: Right, in that case something like the code in your question is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: By the way, to get milliseconds from microseconds, you could do `Micro div 1000`.